# Do Self-Aggregation Simulations Depend Crucially on Radiative-Convective Equilibrium (RCE) Initial Conditions?

Tags: climate, convection, radiative-transfer, radiation-balance

I've been reading papers on convective self-aggregation, such as [Bretherton (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1175/JAS3614.1) and [Khairoutdinov (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(2003)060%3C0607:CRMOTA%3E2.0.CO;2), and it's not clear to me why (or whether) self-aggregation depends on the model being initialised from radiative convective equilibrium (RCE). Are there any papers that show self-aggregation can occur in homogenous, no-shear, non-RCE conditions?

It's possible I'm missing the point of these studies. It may be the idea is more that it's *surprising* aggregation occurs *despite* RCE, because RCE is supposed to represent a balanced equilibrium state. Would this mean aggregation disrupts RCE, and that RCE is actually an "unstable" equilibrium?

Comment: perhaps you should ask a separate question. What is radiative convective equilibrium ? Explain that first and then maybe ask this question linking to that.  I do not think anyone here has actually worked on RCE